# Design time support for user controls, that are containers for other controls

Tags: .net, vb.net, nested-controls

I like to create an user control that (among other controls) contains a panel. Fellow developers should be able to add other controls at design time to the panel of my user control.
Unfortunately all the examples I found on the internet don't seem to work properly (or I do something wrong, what may be more likely).

For all my code snippets I created a new winforms project and added a user control that contains just a panel and nothing else. The panel fills the whole user control.

---

The first solution I found on the net is to attribute my control like this:

```
<Designer("System.Windows.Forms.Design.ParentControlDesigner, System.Design", GetType(IDesigner))> _
Public Class MyUserControl
...
```

When I compile my program and add my user control to a form, I'm able to add other controls to my user control, but I don't see these controls, neither at design time nor runtime. I only see the added controls in my control while dragging my control with the mouse on the form.

---

The second solution I found is to create my own `ControlDesigner`. For this I exposed the panel of my user control to the public, ...

```
Public Class MyUserControl

  Public ReadOnly Property Panel As Panel
    Get
      Return Me.InnerPanel
    End Get
  End Property

End Class
```

... created my very own `ControlDesigner`...

```
Public Class MyUserControlDesigner
  Inherits ParentControlDesigner

  Public Overrides Sub Initialize(ByVal component As IComponent)
    MyBase.Initialize(component)

    If (TypeOf MyBase.Control Is MyUserControl) Then
      MyBase.EnableDesignMode(DirectCast(MyBase.Control, MyUserControl).Panel, "Panel")
    End If
  End Sub

End Class
```

... and changed the attribute of my user control:

```
<Designer(GetType(MyUserControlDesigner))> _
Public Class MyUserControl
...
```

Now I am able to add controls to my user control at design time and I even see these added controls, at least until I start the program.
After that I can't see the added controls anymore because the designer generated code doesn't add these controls to the `Controls` collection of my panel.

Do you have any hint, why it's not working like I want it to work?

Since I like to use the custom `ControlDesigner` anyway, I'd prefer a hint or a solution for the second way.

And I know, that for this example I didn't need to use an user control, I could've inherited from `Panel`. But this is just a simplified example of the control I like to create, so inheriting from `Panel` isn't an option in the end.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this question. The question is quite old, however, if you haven't found any solution, pls try the below:

Download the source code from the below link:

http://addressof.com/articles/transcontrols_pt1.zip

Open up TransPanel.vb and change the

```
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Panel
```

to

```
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.UserControl
```

Build the solution. Now add some random controls to this TransPanel.vb like textboxes or labels.

In the Form1, you can see the earlier TransPanel panel present. Delete it replace with a normal Panel- Panel1.

> Set the background color of panel1 to Transparent.

Load the modified 'TransPanel' usercontrol into your Form1's panel1:

```
Dim f As New TransControls.TransPanel
Panel1.Controls.Add(f)
f.Show()
```

Execute program. You can see that the panel containing the Usercontrol is semi transparent.. With controls!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. When I inherited a Class form the Control i created, the different sub-Controls on it (like a GroupBox, or a Button) were disabled in the designer; they cannot be moved and their properties cannot be edited.

**The solution was to declare the sub-Controls as Public.** First the were Private with a Getter/Setter-Methode making them exposed to the outer world. This worked fine just if the Control was added in the designer on a existing Form or on another Control. But when I opened an inherited class from this Control in the designer, the described problem occurred. Changing the sub-Controls to be Public was a solution to this.